# javascript function hoisting does not works

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

```
function test(flag){
    if (flag) {
        return function test1(){console.log(1)}
    }else{
        return function test1(){console.log(2)}
    }
}
test(true)()
test()()
```

it log 1 and 2,why not double 2？
how does this works

my english is not very good, thank you

this also works with 1 and 2

```
function test(flag){
    if (flag) {
        function test1(){console.log(1)}
        return test1
    }else{
        function test1(){console.log(2)}
        return test1
    }
}
test(true)()
test()()
```

Comment: Thats because in the first call flag is passed as true and hence the true block is executed and in the second call flag will be passed as undefined and so the false block will get executed

Comment: On the first call, `flag` is true, then executes the `if` condition. On the second, `flag` is null, which is false, then executes the `else` condition.

Comment: Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

The function in this line:

```
return function test1(){console.log(2)}
```

Is not a function declaration. It is a *named function expression*, because it is part of a statement.

Function expressions are not hoisted. Only function declarations are hoisted, like this:

```js
function test(){
    return test1;

    function test1() { console.log(1); }
    function test1() { console.log(2); }
}

test()();
```

**Edit:** Regarding the question you added after the fact, function declarations inside conditional expressions have undefined behavior and you can see different results depending on your JavaScript engine. Functions inside `if-else` statements may not be hoisted to the top of the scope, and you should not put function declarations inside conditional expressions. [More about this](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

Comment: `function test(flag){
 if (flag) {
  function test1(){console.log(1)}
  return test1
 }else{
  function test1(){console.log(2)}
  return test1
 }
}
test(true)()
test()()` this also 1 and 2

Comment: `function test(flag){
    if (flag) {
        function test1(){console.log(1)}
        return test1
    }else{
        function test1(){console.log(2)}
        return test1
    }
}
test(true)()
test()()`

Comment: @user1861806 Function declarations inside conditional expressions have undefined behavior and you can see different results depending on your JavaScript engine. Hoisting is not guaranteed inside an `if-else` expression and you should not put functions inside conditional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call `test(true)()` it goes through:

```
if (flag) {
        return function test1(){console.log(1)}
    }
```

because the `flag` has value `true`.

In the second call `test()()` it goes through the `else` path:

```
else{
        return function test1(){console.log(2)}
    }
```

because in that instance value of `flag` is undefined and it evaluates as `false`.

You can get an idea about [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) using these links.

Hope you got the idea here. Please let me know if you have any questions.